# Computer Ram Upgrade

Tags: memory, upgrade, desktop-computer

I've been trying to search different forums and i think i need a little bit help :)

I want to upgrade my computers ram, i know that i first have to figure out how much my processor can handle, but to be honest i really dont know.
I've also came across something about voltage and the motherboard, so i'll give some details of what i have here with a gyazo aswell.

I got the AMD Phenom II x6 1090T:
https://gyazo.com/9b218dabe12fae6fb0ddc9cb21a3fae7?token=af7774c81600e67bcdc65fdc539c5822

My current ram is 2x 4gb DDR3 from Kingston, but im not quite sure what their mhz is as i see two different ones (im a noob sorry):
https://gyazo.com/5c3a21e7ac60248ba38485731a850e0a

So, is my processor actually capable of running more ram? If so, can anyone tell me what kind of MhZ ram i actually have to buy without wasting too much money on something getting downclocked anyways (I read this, lol)
Im also looking into getting a new graphics card, but i'll save that question for later :p

I need more reputation to post more than 2 links, so if you need information about my motherboard its the Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd. GA-870A-USB3 :)

Regards.

Comment: Just search RAM for GA-870A-USB3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limitation on RAM capacity is usually determined by the motherboard.

For a [GA-870A-USB3](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-870A-USB3-rev-31#sp), that's 32 GB *total*.

As you already have Kingston RAM, I suggest looking at the labels on the RAM to determine the part number, and then go through the Kingston memory selector to see if that part number is still current.

For your board, that's [ValueRAM for Gigabyte GA-870-UD3P Motherboard](https://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search?DeviceType=7&Mfr=GIG&Line=GA-870-UD3P&Model=73055).

You will have to check the prices in your country, but it may well be cheapest to add the "16GB Kit*(2x8GB) - DDR3 1600MHz Part Number: KVR16N11K2/16" and let it automatically run at a lower speed than it is to get an exact match to the current RAM speed and have to buy two sticks separately.

**Edit:** Apparently you have KHX1600C9D3/4g RAM, which should be 1600 MHz RAM with a CAS of 9 at that speed. I will modify my previous suggestion to note that that exact RAM is available on eBay etc. for fairly reasonable prices.

Comment: @Kristian Thanks for your confidence in my answer, but if I were you I would check back in a few hours just in case someone sees something that I've missed.

Comment: I had to shutdown my pc in order to check the numbers :p 
On the label it says: "KHX1600C9D3/4g" would that fit with the 16gb kit, and thank you for the quick answer, i've been "googling" how much my motherboard is capable of and i simply couldnt find it lol.
I will keep an eye on this post :)

Comment: @Kristian Ah... do you know what frequency the RAM is actually running at? The screenshot you showed appears to not show the full capability of it. You might be better off getting higher-performance RAM than the ValueRAM line. What performance aspect of your computer are you intending to improve?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/1bd4832fe319d6a3c3e3bc45a70fee76

I'm planning to switch out my Radeon HD 6970 2gb to a better, newer and higher gb, the radeon hd 6970 is known to get very hot, like 90c but mine is reaching 100c unless i overclock with fan speed up to 70% which is annoying, and probably damaging the fans over the long run. (i've got the paste changed and cleaned it for dust, its just getting old i guess)
Im pretty much planning to upgrade the processor aswell, but electronic is expensive, so i thought i would start with the ram and then the gpu :)

Comment: @Kristian OK, it looks like the current RAM may be overkill. If you get any useful information from [Phenom II X6 ram supported speeds](http://www.overclock.net/t/1358803/phenom-ii-x6-ram-supported-speeds) it may be worth reporting it back here. Again, why do you want to increase the RAM?

Comment: In the near future i am going to work with games and alot of programs that could require my computer having more ram, atleast that was what i thought after reading this:
http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question175.htm

I've seen a guy who said that "a rule of thumb" is that your GPU is half the size of the RAM (i dont know if that is true) and considering i want to upgrade my GPU from 2gb to a higher one i thought that was what i was going to need. :)

Comment: @Kristian You should check the "computer requirements" section of the software you're going to use: your current 8 GB may be enough for what you're doing. The HowStuffWorks article you referred to appears to be about 15 years old (look at the dates of the references) - things have changed since then.